# How to avoid duplicate in ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

> I have used a for loop to add the student details to ArrayList. When I give second student details, it overwrites the first data.
>   Stud class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Stud {
    private int rollNumber, age;
    private String firstName, lastName, gender;
    public Stud(int rollNumber, String firstName, String lastName, int age, String gender) {

    }
    public void setRollnumber(int rollNumber) {
        this.rollNumber=rollNumber;
    }
    public int getRollnumber() {
        return rollNumber;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstName) {
        this.firstName=firstName;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastName) {
        this.lastName=lastName;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age=age;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender=gender;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
}
```

> Main class to add the data to ArrayList.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Stud> al=new ArrayList<Stud>();
        System.out.println("Enter the details:");
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
        int rollNumber;
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        int age;
        String gender;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);      
        rollNumber=in.nextInt();
        firstName=in.next();
        lastName=in.next();
        age=in.nextInt();
        gender=in.next();

        Stud s=new Stud(rollNumber, firstName, lastName, age, gender);

            al.add(s);

            for (Stud stud : al) {
                stud.setRollnumber(rollNumber);
                System.out.println(stud.getRollnumber());
            }
        }           

    }

}
```

> Output: actual output for roll number [1] after second data [2,2].
>   Expected output should be Roll Number: A1
>   Name: F1 L1
>   Gender: Male
>   Age: 11
>   Sports Event: Javelin
>
> ### Eligibility: No (Since Javelin is open for the students 15 and above)

Roll Number: A2
Name: F2 L2
Gender: Female
Age: 14
Sports Event: 100 meter run

### Eligibility: Yes

Roll Number: A3
Name: F3 L3
Gender: Male
Age: 11
Sports Event: 50 meter run
Eligibility: No (Only for girls ageing 10 to 12)

Comment: If you do not want duplicates in a list, you should use a set. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html

Comment: What's the use for the last `for` loop?

Comment: Your print loop also updates roll numbers for all students

Comment: Last for loop is to print ArrayList data. Any Idea to avoid overwriting of first list data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work:

```
public class MainClass {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Set<Stud> al=new HashSet<>(); // use a set
       Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in); // init scanner here!
       System.out.println("Enter the details:");
       for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
           int rollNumber;
           String firstName;
           String lastName;
           int age;
           String gender;

           rollNumber=in.nextInt();
           firstName=in.next();
           lastName=in.next();
           age=in.nextInt();
           gender=in.next();

           Stud s=new Stud(rollNumber, firstName, lastName, age, gender);

           al.add(s);

           for (Stud stud : al) {
               System.out.println(stud.getRollnumber());
           }
       }
   }

private static class Stud {
    private final int rollNumber, age;
    private final String firstName, lastName;
    private final String gender;

    // assign the values you get in constructor
    public Stud(int rollNumber, String firstName, String lastName, int age, String gender) {
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public int getRollnumber() {
        return this.rollNumber;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstName;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastName;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return this.rollNumber;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return this.gender;
    }

    // needed for Set
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + this.age;
        result = prime * result + ((this.firstName == null) ? 0 : this.firstName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((this.gender == null) ? 0 : this.gender.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((this.lastName == null) ? 0 : this.lastName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + this.rollNumber;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Stud other = (Stud) obj;
        if (this.age != other.age)
            return false;
        if (this.firstName == null) {
            if (other.firstName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!this.firstName.equals(other.firstName))
            return false;
        if (this.gender == null) {
            if (other.gender != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!this.gender.equals(other.gender))
            return false;
        if (this.lastName == null) {
            if (other.lastName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!this.lastName.equals(other.lastName))
            return false;
        if (this.rollNumber != other.rollNumber)
            return false;
        return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you only removed the `setRoleNumber` within the `for`. - duplicates are still allowed. You should update your answer with `equals` and `getHashCode` etc.

Comment: updated. I think the problem was not the "duplicates", but rather the scanner initialized in the loop again and again. Therefore it always read the firstly entered values. Now my solution doesnt allow duplicates anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use the `Stream` class in Java 8, you can use `distinct`:

```
list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

An ´equals`-method for your objects is essential.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you asked,Hope this works. It doesn't have problem with overwriting of previous record. Use Iterator class to add records to the arraylist.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ArraLis {

    private int rollNumber, age;
    private String firstName, lastName, gender,event;
    ArraLis(int rollnum, String fname, String lname, int ag, String gend,String even) {
        rollNumber=rollnum;
        age=ag;
        gender=gend;
        firstName=fname;
        lastName=lname;
        event=even;
    }
    public void setRollnumber(int rollNumber) {
        this.rollNumber=rollNumber;
    }
    public int getRollnumber() {
        return rollNumber;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstName) {
        this.firstName=firstName;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastName) {
        this.lastName=lastName;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age=age;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender=gender;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<ArraLis> al=new ArrayList<ArraLis>();
    System.out.println("enter the details");
    int rollNumber;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int age;
    String gender;
    String event;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
    rollNumber=in.nextInt();
    firstName=in.next();
    lastName=in.next();
    age=in.nextInt();
    gender=in.next();
    event=in.next();


    ArraLis a1=new ArraLis(rollNumber, firstName, lastName, age, gender, event);
    al.add(a1);

    }
    Iterator it=al.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        ArraLis ar=(ArraLis)it.next();
        System.out.println(ar.rollNumber+" "+ar.firstName+" "+ar.lastName+" "+ar.age+" "+ar.gender+" "+ar.event);
    }



}
}
```